# DjangoCMS: Public Link to Preview

Tags: django-cms

I made some changes to a DjangoCMS page. These changes are unpublished up to now.

I would like to show this unpublished page to someone who has no login to DjangoCMS.

Is there a way to create a public link to show the unpublished page to someone?

Answer (score 1):

There are parameters/plugins you can set that may help, specifically admin_preview  and render_plugin_block under CMSPluginBase.  But for the most part, Django-cms doesn't allow you to perform that action.

What you can do is create a public user account, with a simple username and password you can give out.  This public user account can have permission setup that ensures it has only view abilities, and you can restrict what pages it can see.  Thus you can restrict the page just to the one you would like them to view, you can then give them access to it through the regular url.

Specifically, you'll want to look into CMS_PERMISSION and form there at Page-specific permissions and then at View restrictions and then at Page permissions.

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/topics/permissions.html